# Compare two tables td for same class and copy content to second table

Tags: jquery

I have two tables.

I want to compare two tables and if the `td` have the same class (e.g. `id-1 == id-1`) I want to copy and replace from first `table` the second `td` to second `table` at first `td`.

```js
$('.table1 tr td:first-child').each(function() {
  var firstTableClass = $(this).attr('class');
  $('.table2 tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') === firstTableClass) {
      $(this).html($('.table1 tr td:last-child').html());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1" border="1">
<caption>Table 1</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-1">1</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-2">2</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table2" border="1">
<caption>Table 2</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-1">1</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-2">2</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that copy the first Name only in all `td`.

I want the Table 2 to have this results

```
<table class="table2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="id-1">Name</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-2">Name 2</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4zf2bL0/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to modify your html as well? Your question also makes it sound like you want to copy the innerHTML of the <td> element with the same class name, but you're really looking to copy the innerHTML from the following occurance of a <td> element from your examples? Some clarification there would be nice.

Comment: Well, I tried it out and it already works! I don't see any problems.

Comment: `$(this).html($('.table1 tr td:last-child').html());`  Is too global of a selector.  It needs to use the `this` from the first each and to go the next sibling instead.

Comment: @TCooper here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e4zf2bL0/. Yes i want to copy the innerHTML of the <td> element with the same class name. As you see the second table second row first td is wrong (it was supposed to be Name 2).

Comment: @Aaron3219 the problem is at second table have two times the same name.

Comment: Ah, got it. I see the problem(you're always grabbing the first tr of the first table in your inner most loop). Don't have a solution off the top of my head. I'll let you know if I figure something out

Comment: ximt, if the answer I provided worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: @TCooper sorry. I was busy. Thank you very much!

Comment: NP, just fishing for rep in case I need a bounty on something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: the problem is you're always grabbing the first `tr` of the first `table` in your inner most loop.

Adding a counter for each iteration and using the `:eq()` selector for the `tr` should do the trick.

```js
$('.table1 tr td:first-child').each(function() {
  var firstTableClass = $(this).attr('class');
  var i = 0;
  $('.table2 tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') === firstTableClass) {
      $(this).html($('.table1 tr:eq(' + i + ') td:last-child').html());
    }
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1" border="1">
  <caption>Table 1</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-1">1</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-2">2</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table2" border="1">
  <caption>Table 2</caption>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-1">1</td>
    <td>2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id-2">2</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feonsa9c/  <-- fiddle here

Comment: NP. Odd, it says my edit was rejected, yet here it is. Much to learn about SO I have...

Comment: yeah, usually can see who edited it as well, I thought.